# How to find out which process is accessing my files?

Tags: security

On May 22, 2023, then again in June, July and August 8, 2023 the last access date on the files in my home director were changed. Most of these files I haven't accessed in years.

How do I find out the name of the process that is doing this? My first guess is Google but I have no proof. I looked into `journalctl` but it isn't that granular and has nothing meaningful of programs running at that time.

I have no problems writing a script that runs once a minute and checks the last access date of `~/secret_file.txt` or whatever trap is set, but I'm not sure on the exact script I should run.

Similar question with no explicit answer: [How do I see what program accessed my files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124669/how-do-i-see-what-program-accessed-my-files)

Not a duplicate question because that link doesn't suggest setting a trap by creating a file that is never accessed such as `~/my_secrets.txt`. Also that question never offered willingness to create a script that runs every minute. Whatever program is accessing my files is probably internet based because I have an nvme SSD that can quickly access files but the POG (Program of Interst) in question takes many minutes to access all the files in `~`. In the last August 8th instance I noticed (two days after the fact) it was from 9:01 am to 9:04 am.

Is there already a package that lets you plant a trap and see who springs it? If not how do you see what is running at that time and get a notification? Anything that can change the world, I say or post publicly anyway, so there is nothing on my computer to hide. I just resent the fact something or someone is looking into my home directory.

Comment: Sounds like tripwire, but that might be more enterprise oriented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monitor what files are opened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34158/how-to-monitor-what-files-are-opened)

Comment: Check your system logs around the timr your files were changed. Add to your `~/.bashrc`: `alias tsjou="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"` then `source ~/.bashrc`. You can use this alias to format dates for the `journalctl` `--since=` and `--before` options. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Related: [File Access dates changed unexpectedly. Metadata crawler?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1454511)